# DNS resolution is not working until dnsmasq is restarted

Tags: dns, wireshark, dnsmasq

Name resolution is not working until dnsmasq is restarted manually. Packet captures says that it is refused in nonworking scenario. what could be the cause for this issue? How can I debug further? Is there any clue with the below pcaps?
[image]

Comment: Sounds like your domain controller is being slow. Dnsmasq is likely flagging with URG.

Comment: what do you mean by URG? Why it starts working when i restart?

Comment: Compare the packets that go to the DNS server before and after Dnsmasq is run, and look at the flags on tge packets. URG is "process this data first." If your domain controller is slow for some reason, you'll notice, but URG-flagged packets will take the least time.